# How to update system databases in SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having problems updating a system database in SQL Server 2008. Perhaps there is a different way to do it, but I basically need to change/remove growth restrictions on certain log files for a bunch of databases.

Being lazy, instead of doing this manually for each of the 100 databases using SSMS, I thought I could create a batch query.

First, this information is visible through the `sys.master_files` view:

```
select database_id, name, max_size 
from sys.master_files
```

And through [this link ("How to update system tables in SQL 2008 R2")](http://yrushka.com/index.php/database-maintenance/how-to-update-system-tables-sql-2008-r2-fix-ad-hoc-updates-to-system-catalogs-are-not-allowed/), I found out that the relevant database for this view is actually `sys.sysbrickfiles`:

[image: Execution plan reveals actual databases]

But even after connecting with `sqlcmd` and using `sp_configure 'allow updates', 1`, querying the `sys.sysbrickfiles` returns `"Invalid object name 'sys.sysbrickfiles'"`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update sys.brickfiles manually, you're required to use the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  This *is* available via SQLCMD; you just need to type `ADMIN:` before the servername.

[Insert generic warning about being careful and having backups here.]

Conversely, you could loop through a list of databases and change the autogrowth settings that way (quick scribble based on something I had lying around;  you'll probably need to modify it):

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
        @RowsToProcess int,
        @CurrentRow int = 0,
        @dbname nvarchar(80)

CREATE TABLE #dblist(RowID int not null identity(1,1), dbname nvarchar(50) )  
INSERT into #dblist (dbname) SELECT name FROM sys.databases where name not in ('master','msdb','model','tempdb')

SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT


WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
    SELECT 
        @dbname=dbname FROM #dblist WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow
        set @SQL='ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + ']  MODIFY FILE (NAME=N''' + @DBName + '_Log'', FILEGROWTH=20MB);'
        print @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL             
END


drop table #dblist
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for the second approach, it worked without a dedicated admin connection! Typical newbie, went in a completely wrong direction. :)